# android application resetting to older version

Tags: android, installation

I have made an app which is pre-installed on android device of particular manufacturer. After this I have release an upgrade of application for example initial version 1.0.0.0 to upgrade version of 1.2.0.0. After upgrading the app if user restarts its phone then my application goes to the initial version of 1.0.0.0.

Don't know why this is happening ? Is there a problem in bundling the application to devices ?

Note: I am updating my app via my server and not from play store and this issue is reproducible only when app is pre-installed on devices.

In mainfest file of both the versions I forgot to change android:versionCode value, in both the versions android:versionCode=3. Is it creating problem because of this?

I have also changed the package name of Application class so is this is creating the problem ?

Manifest for first version:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.apps.spinr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SpinrTheme"
            android:name="com.abc.xyz.GDApplication">
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Mainfest for second version:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.xxx.apps.spinr"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.2.0.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


            <application
                android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/SpinrTheme"
                android:name="com.xxx.apps.GDApplication">
                <activity
                    android:name=".SplashActivity"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is still version 1? What differences do you expect, that you dont see.

Comment: in settings -> Apps -> MyApp there version is 1.0.0.0 after restart instead of upgraded version 1.2.0.0. And when I starts the app i find older version of the app

Comment: was it version 1.2 in settings before you restarted?

Comment: yes, and this problem occurs only in those devices in which app is pre-installed. I have tried this in other devices in which app is not pre-installed upgraded version works normally and in settings version shown is 1.2.0.0.

Comment: Actually, google play never release update for the app with the same version code, so you must change version code to be 2. maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Mahmoud Google play does issue an error before the app is loaded up there if the version codes are the same. prateek may be its the application name that causes the issue, go through the entire play store listing (publish app screen) and under devices supported, you will know which devices have the old version and theres somewhere where they mention the reason why an old version is being used and never updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. As @Mahmoud in comment suggested that "google play never release update for the app with the same version code", so I incremented version code of app and it worked fine. @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille as I said in question I am not updating my app via google play neither my app is on play store so I was not able to figure this out initially. Anyways thanks for help.

So conclusion is

> **whenever you want to send upgrade of app always increase version code
>   of the app**